# Passing .PEM and .KEY using CakePHP HttpSocket

Tags: cakephp, ssl

I am trying to use HttpSocket to perform an operation i usually do using cURL which passing .PEM and .KEY along with my request.

I know you can specify the path of your CA file using ssl_cafile but couldn't find a way to pass the .key! is this even possible?!

cURL way:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $pemfile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE, 'PEM'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, $keyfile);
```

HttpSocket way to pass pem file:

```
App::uses('HttpSocket', 'Network/Http');
$Socket = new HttpSocket(array(
             'ssl_cafile'=>'/file.pem',
             ));
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So far it's impossible you have to use your own implementation of Curl.